# A permanent list change(Save python file)

Tags: python-3.x

I am a noob in python and i need help.I have made a phonebook where you can add the contacts.But the problem is that when i exit the program the changes to the list are not saved.I want the user to be able to make permanent changes to the list.I have seen posts about a file=open("something",'w') code to do this(I think) but i dont know where to insert this code and i dont really understand what it is.Could someone help me understand what this is about..Here is the full code:

```
name = ["ranga","hari"]
number = [9895497777,9]
book = {name[0]:number[0],name[1]:number[1]}
def search():
    print("Contacts:")
    for x in book:
        print(x,':',book[x])
    while 1:
        count = 0
        a = 0
        ch1 = input("search: ")
        try:
            ch1 = int(ch1)
        except ValueError:
            while a < len(name):
                result = name[a].find(ch1)
                if result == -1:
                    a = a + 1
                else:
                    print(name[a],number[a])
                    a = a + 1
                    count = count + 1
            if count == 0:
                print("Not available.Try again")
                continue
            else:
                break
        ch1 = str(ch1)
        while a < len(number):
            sumber = str(number[a])
            result = sumber.find(ch1)
            if result == -1:
                a = a + 1
            else:
                print(name[a],number[a])
                a = a + 1
                count += 1
        if count == 0:
            print("Not available.try again")
            continue
        else:
            break


def add():
    print("What is the name of the contact you want to add?")
    name1 = input()
    name.append(name1)
    while 1:
        print("What is the number of this contact?")
        number1 = input()
        try:
            number1 = int(number1)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type a number..")
            continue
        number.append(number1)
        book[name1] = number1
        break
def remoe():
    print("Reference:")
    for x in book:
        print(x,':',book[x])
    while 1:
        print("What is the name of the contact you want to remove?")
        name2 = input()
        if name2 in book:
            increment = name.index(name2)
            name.pop(increment)
            number.pop(increment)
            del book[name2]
            break
        else:
            print("Not available.Please try again")
while 1:
    print("Contacts:")
    for x in book:
        print(x, ':', book[x])
    print("\nWhat do you want to do?\n1.Search for a person\n2.edit the phone book\n3.exit")
    choice = input()
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        print("Type 1,2 or 3")
        continue
    if choice == 1:
        search()
    elif choice == 2:
        while 1:
            print("Do you want to:\n1.Add a contact\n2.Remove a contact\n3.Go back to main menu")
            ch2 = input()
            if ch2 in['3']:
                break
            else:
                try:
                    ch2 = int(ch2)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Type 1 or 2..")
                if ch2 == 1:
                    add()
                elif ch2 == 2:
                    remoe()
    elif choice == 3:
        exit()
    else:
        print("Type 1,2 or 3")
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to `add` a contact, it does properly add the name and number to the list. But, that is it.

When you re-run the program, the list gets re-assigned due to the first `2` lines of your code:

```
name = ["ranga","hari"]
number = [9895497777,9]
```

So, you won't see the last changes.

This is where you should maintain a `file` which lives outside the scope of your code, rather than a list.

You can modify your `add` function like this:

```
def add():
    print("What is the name of the contact you want to add?")
    name1 = input()
    #name.append(name1) 
    # Just add the name1 variable's value to the file
    with open('contacts_list.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(name1 + '\n')

    while 1:
        print("What is the number of this contact?")
        number1 = input()
        try:
            number1 = int(number1)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type a number..")
            continue
        #number.append(number1)
        # Similarly, append the number1 variable's value to file again.
        with open('contacts_list.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(number1)
        #book[name1] = number1
        with open('contacts_list.txt', 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
        break
```

**Note:** You would also need to change the other functions `search` and `remove` to read and write from the file. I've just given you a taste of how things are done. You need to modify your code and make it work.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried your code for add() but when writing number1 value to file it shows an TypeError saying unsupported operand type(s) for +: int and str.I tried to find out what is wrong but it is impossible..but thanks for the fast response

Comment: Just remove `+ \n` from that command. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man.i figured out how to prevent the errors but it still doesnt save the changes permanently..i even closed the file but still not working.what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Got it. Change `a+` to `w+` in that command. Check my updated asnwer.

Comment: Ok now last question,you know at the main menu it prints the contacts.well how do i do that..Im sorry if i seem a bit annoying

Comment: Check my updated answer.  You might have to do some formatting to print in the way you like.

Answer (score 1):

I took your advice and made a new text file but i still did not know how to do it but after reading ur answers i understood and at last i came to this..

```
removelist = []

def search():
    while 1:
        search = str(input("Search: "))
        if search not in["exit", "Exit"]:
            with open('output.txt', 'r+') as f:
                line = f.readline()
                while line:
                    data = line.find(search)
                    if not data == -1:
                        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
                        line = f.readline()
                    else:
                        line = f.readline()
        else:
            break
        f.close()
def add():
    print("Type the name of the contact:")
    name = input()
    while 1:
        print("Type the number of this contact:")
        number = input()
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type a number")
            continue
        number = str(number)
        with open('output.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write('\n' + name +' ' + number)
            break
def remoe(): #this is where the problem comes in
    while 1:
        remove = str(input("Remove: "))
        with open('output.txt', 'r+') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                if not remove in["Remove", "remove"]:
                    removelist.clear()
                    data = line.find(remove)
                    if not data == -1:
                        removelist.append(line) #This saves all the lines coming from the search to a
                        print(removelist)       #removelist which can be accessed when you type in remove
                        line = f.readline()     #But the problem is that if there is a \n at the end of the
                    else:                       #string then the remove function does not work
                        line = f.readline()
                else:
                    print(removelist)
                    with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
                        d = f.readlines()
                        f.close()
                    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
                        for i in d:
                            if i not in removelist:
                                f.write(i)
                        f.truncate()
                        f.close()
                    break

while 1:
    with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        print("Contacts:")
        print(data)
        print('''What do you want to do?
        1.Search for a contact
        2.Edit contacts
        3.Exit''')
    f.close()
    choice = input()
    if choice in["1"]:
        search()
    elif choice in["2"]:
        while 1:
            print('''What do you wanna do:
             1.Add a contact
             2.Remove a contact
             3.Exit to main menu''')
            ch1 = input()
            if ch1 in["1"]:
                add()
            elif ch1 in["2"]:
                remoe()
            elif ch1 in["3"]:
                break
            else:
                print("Please type 1,2 or 3")
    elif choice in[3]:
        print("Ok bye")
    else:
        print("Please type 1,2 or 3")
```

Now the problem seems to be the remove function..if i try to remove a line with \n at the end of it then it wont work while the opp. seems to work.Any guess what i am doing here?
And thanks for the help Mayank porwal

Answer (score 0):

At the first you should know name = ["ranga","hari"], number = [9895497777,9] that you have defined are in the code and you can not change those value, and after exit() they will reset to default value.

you should use of file (for example .txt file) in this issue:
1. you must create a .txt file in your project (for example Contacts.txt)
2. and write your information in there (for example in first line: Kourosh +98938....)
3. at the first step in your program you must read Contact.txt and load it in a structure like a list or dictionary (for example

```
>>> with open('workfile') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
```

)

4.now you can edit, add, remove structure.
5.and finally you can write structure in the file, before exit()
for example:

```
>>> with open('workfile') as f:
    ...     f.write(s)
    >>> f.closed
```

Comment: Wow!Thanks for the fast reply.But i still do not understand..could you maybe give an example?Thanks anyway